# Как отобразить календарь на angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

Хочу вывести на страницу календарь используя angular
Вот код:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="mwl.calendar.docs">
<head>
    <title>Catalog</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/angular-bootstrap-calendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular-bootstrap-calendar-tpls.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="OptionalEventEndDatesCtrl as vm">
        <ng-include src="'calendarControls.html'"></ng-include>
        <mwl-calendar events="vm.events"
                      view="vm.calendarView"
                      view-date="vm.viewDate">
        </mwl-calendar>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        angular.module('mwl.calendar.docs').controller('OptionalEventEndDatesCtrl', function (moment, calendarConfig) {

            var vm = this;

            vm.events = [{
                title: 'No event end date',
                startsAt: moment().hours(3).minutes(0).toDate(),
                color: calendarConfig.colorTypes.info
            }, {
                title: 'No event end date',
                startsAt: moment().hours(5).minutes(0).toDate(),
                color: calendarConfig.colorTypes.warning
            }];

            vm.calendarView = 'day';
            vm.viewDate = new Date();

        });
    </script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Использую как пример вот эти ресурсы:

```
[https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-bootstrap-calendar#installation][1]
```

[mattlewis92.github.io/angular-bootstrap-calendar/#!?example=optional-event-end-dates](http://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-bootstrap-calendar/#!?example=optional-event-end-dates)

Но отображается пустая страница. Что надо подключить чтобы заработало?

Comment: У Вас нигде не инициализируется Ваше `ng-app`. Посмотрите в консоли, angular там на что-нибудь в этом духе и ругается (хотя в .min варианте сообщения могут быть невразумительными, используйте для отладки не минифицированную версию).

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду вот так var myapp = angular.module('mwl.calendar.docs')

Comment: @АнтонЕвсеев, скорее `angular.module('mwl.calendar.docs',[])`

Comment: @Grundy угу, только вряд ли просто `[]`. Как минимум, сам модуль календаря в зависимостях упомянуть придется. :)